# How to get Virtual PC to recognize MIDI devices?

Tags: windows-7, midi, midi-virtual-keyboard

Hey all. I have an XP Pro virtual machine running inside Virtual PC 2007. My host machine is x64 Windows 7. I have a MIDI keyboard hooked up to my machine via a Turtle Beach USB to MIDI 1x1 cable. I have installed the driver and software on my host machine and ran a soundcheck, and everything appears to be working fine. Playback is sent to the MIDI device with no problems. However, when I attempt to install the driver and run a soundcheck in my XP virtual machine, the device is not found. Other USB devices (mouse, keyboard, flash drives) work fine in the virtual machine, but not they MIDI keyboard. I'm not sure what steps to take in order to troubleshoot the and get the VM to start recognizing the MIDI keyboard. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

1. Run your virtual machine.
2. Disconnect your MIDI keyboard from your host machine (physically) in case it's connected
3. Connect your MIDI keyboard again
   In this case you should see on your guest machine the driver for your midi keyboard is being installed

Do not forget to enable your keyboard in your music sequencer after these steps.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm.  I'm not sure about USB pass through on Virtual PC, but all of the working devices you described are very common devices.  I've used usb passthrough with VMWare, and have had success with a huge variety of USB devices, including USB displays and sound cards.

If you aren't tied to using Virutal PC, you could give VMWare Server a shot which is free, and you could try that.